# Repetir n veces cada elemento de una lista en python

Tags: python

ayuda por favor, necesito que cada elemento de la lista se repita un cierto numero de veces y que se guarden en una nueva lista:

Tengo la siguiente lista
a=['c1','c2', 'c3']

El resultado que esperaria seria

```
 out():['c1','c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2','c2','c3','c3','c3','c3']
```

Esto es lo que estaba intentando hacer pero se genera un resultado erroneo

```
 b=[]
 for i in itertools.repeat(a,4):
        b.append(i)
```

Ayuda por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se puede resolver con Python básico:

```
def repetir(lista, veces):
    salida = []
    for elemento in lista:
        salida.extend([elemento] * veces)
    return salida
```

Esta función recibe una lista y el número de repeticiones deseadas.

Crea una lista vacia. Por cada elemento en la lista de entrada, **extiende** la lista de salida con esto:

```
[elemento] * veces
```

Esta sintaxis genera una lista con repeticiones del elemento. Ejemplo:

```
['1'] * 3 => ['1', '1', '1']
```

Hay que usar `extend`, pues queremos agregar los elementos de la lista, no la lista.

Al terminar de recorrer la lista, retornamos la lista generada.

#### Demo

```
def repetir(lista, veces):
    salida = []
    for elemento in lista:
        salida.extend([elemento] * veces)
    return salida


a=['c1','c2', 'c3']

print(repetir(a, 4))
```

produce:

```
['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c3', 'c3']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Vanessa si la respuesta de Candid Moe te resulto útil, puedes marcarla como aceptada presionando la tildecita a la izquierda de la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes multiplicar una lista n veces, y se repetiran sus valores.

```
resultado = []
n_repetir = 4
a=['c1','c2', 'c3']

for v in a:
    l = [v] * n_repetir
    resultado = resultado + l

print(resultado) # ['c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c3', 'c3', 'c3', 'c3']
```